# Embedded jetty maven profile.xml

Tags: java, maven, jetty, wicket

I try to start jetty in embedded form but i have problems

I need to read properties values in profile.xml before embedded jetty starts.

Any suggestions ?

Here is profile.xml's content

```
.....
  <profile>
            <id>local-dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- Common Security Framework Properties -->
                <security.context.file>applicationContext-security-csf.xml</security.context.file>
                <csf.jndi.name>jdbc/securityDS</csf.jndi.name>
                <csf.security.system.admin.roleId>884</csf.security.system.admin.roleId>              
                <csf.cas.url>tkvwasa01.secure.kodcu.com</csf.cas.url>
                <application.service.url>localhost:8080/pqis-admin</application.service.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
```

At maven side i can activate above profile (local-dev) like

mvn jetty:run local-dev

but how can i activate above profile (local-dev) when i use Embedded Jetty ?

Embedded Jetty 's code :

```
public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();

        // Set some timeout options to make debugging easier.
        connector.setMaxIdleTime(1000 * 60 * 60);
        connector.setSoLingerTime(-1);
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });

        WebAppContext bb = new WebAppContext();
        bb.setServer(server);
        bb.setContextPath("/");
        bb.setWar("src/main/webapp");
                .....
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What problems do you have?  Perhaps you should post your relevant pom snippet, assuming you are trying it start it through maven

Comment: When you run your embedded jetty (Start class), how would maven come into picture?

Comment: maven doesn't come into picture so Start.java can't access profile.xml content

Answer (score 0):

Is this profile active by default? Is another profile active? An active-by-default profile will be disabled if another profile is active.

**[edited]**

Well, [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) states that you can activate profiles from the command line using the -P option:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P profile-1,profile-2
```

But, POM properties are not intended to be used in runtime, but in build time. You could, for example, use these properties to [filter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) resources (XML/.properties config files), replacing placeholder tokens with the properties' values. And then, run the built application.